# Facebook insights for personal page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I was wondering if it's possible to get some kind of insights,using facebook graph,  for the personal profile.
Basically I want to know some demographic information(age,gender,location) about the user who shared, liked my feed posts.

I found on the internet that wolfram alpha can do this, although I tried using my profile and besides some information about me, it didn't show any demographic data.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=facebook+report

So do you know how get I get some demographic data about the persons who liked/shared my posts.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Not possible at all. Without authorization, you can´t get any detail of the user - for obvious privacy reasons. Insights are for Pages only.

Comment: Yes but i'm going to request persmissions to the user who is going to be "analyzed". In this case if I have he's permissions isn't possible to get demographic info about the users liked/shared hi' posts. I mean this is what wolfram is basically doing. Also I found on the internet many websites that are doing soccial media analysis.

Comment: no, you can´t get demographic details about users who did not authorize your app, see my answer. there´s no insights for general demographic info either.